# Qt/QuickFIX - doesn't find some header files

Tags: qt, mingw, qt-creator, quickfix

I am using both Qt Framework and QuickFIX engine to create a financial application with GUI.
My problem is that when I compile a program that implements QickFIX engine and Qt Framework, it gives me a compilation error: it doesn't find some header files in MinGW (`socket.h`, `inet/in.h`, etc)

I am on Windows 7 and I know that to use sockets you must use `winsock.h` and so on, but the problem is I have Visual C++ express edition and it's not supported by Qt, so I used Qt Creator and since I have an open source of Qt, QuickFIX engine uses the header files of Linux (`socket.h`, etc) rather than windows. So it gave me an error.
Please can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: What's the issue?  I'm sure QuickFix uses Winsock

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio Express 2010 with Qt. You will need to build Qt with it. When you configure make sure to specify Visual Studio 2010 as the make spec.
Last time I built it got hung up on a couple of projects. To get around this you need to clear out some temporary files that Nokia packaged in the installer for some reason. Just google the error for details.

Once you have Qt built you ought to be able to qmake -tp vc your project and then load up the generated Visual Studio project file.